# Binary Search Query does not return the correct answer

Tags: python, binary-search

I am testing this function to see if it returns the correct answer on whether a particular value exist. However, for every input it returns False. I'm not sure what is wrong in the code.

```
    def BinarySearch(filename, column, l, r, keyword): 

      import csv
      newlist = []

      with open(filename, newline='', encoding="utf-8-sig") as csvfile:
         reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

         for row in reader:
            if row[column] != "":
               newlist.append(row[column])
               sorted_list = sorted(list(map(int, newlist)))

         if r >= l:
            mid = l +(r-l)//2

         if sorted_list[mid] == int(keyword):
            return mid

         elif sorted_list[mid] > int(keyword):
            return BinarySearch(filename, column, l, mid - 1, keyword)
      
         else:
            return BinarySearch(filename, column, mid + 1, r, keyword)
       else:
         return -1
    
    

  keyword = input("Enter your keyword: ")
  result = BinarySearch('bl_printed_music_500.csv', 'Publication date (standardised)', 0, len('Publication date (standardised)')-1, keyword)

  if result != -1:
     print(True)
  else:
     print(False)
```

Comment: Use a debugger or add a few "print"s. First of all I would print "sorted_list" after the for-loop to see if loading worked correctly.

Comment: In order to help you, I believe more information is necessary. You could put, for instance an excerpt of the file you are working with.
I don't think it's a good idea working with recursion with a file like you are doing.

Comment: Hi, try to distinguish between the algorithm and the process of reading the file. It will helps you to find the root cause of the bug.